# Most efficient way to change color of part of a skspritenode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, skspritenode

So I know how to change the color of the entire sprite node but is there a way to say change the color of only the arms of a character or is the only way to do this through assigning the sprite a new image with the appropriate color? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: So long as you have something else that defines or separates the arms by size or position, you can mask them out, and then colour them uniquely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to change the color of only a part of a `SKSpriteNode` can only be done with other nodes involved. But I only recommend this if the area you are changing color of is simple, such as a rect or circle. To do this, I also recommend you use a `SKNode` to wrap its child nodes.

For example:

```
var character = SKNode()

var characterImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"yourImage.png")
//Set sizes, anchor points, what not
character.addChild(characterImage)

var colorChanger = SKSpriteNode(color: yourColor, size: size of arms or whatever)
//Set position -> (colorChange.position)
colorChanger.name = "colorizer"
character.addChild(colorChanger )
```

With this, you can also change the color of the arms whenever you want, using `childNode(withName:)` to access `colorChanger`.

But, if the arms *are* to complicated, you do have to use separate images. Using a `SKNode` to then wrap these images is recommended as well.

PS: If you're new to Swift and Spritekit, the reason it's better to use `SKNodes` as wrappers is because it makes it much easier to move them, rotate them, etc, because you just need to change the location, rotation, etc, of one node instead of many.

Comment: This explains a lot! Unfortunately the arms are fairly complex so I'll just have to use another image then. But thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to change the color property of a specific part of the same SKSpriteNode. Something you could do is to make textures of the colors you need the sprite to be and change the texture property instead of the color.